# Do we still use “for” like “because”?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, formality, writing

I was wondering if the use of “for” like “because” was current use.

For example: “I haven’t come to the party, for I was tired.”

Is this used nowadays?

Or shall we say “I haven’t come to the party because I was tired” otherwise?

Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Welcome! I don't think anyone uses "for" in this context nowadays.  It sounds very out of date.

Comment: For he's a jolly good fellow!

Comment: So I should only use because instead?

Comment: Thank you very much. It does help me lots! I realized I’ve been talking weird with “for” since a long time. I’ll use because instead.